# Error from codeigniter restful api

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter-3

I am using  Phil Sturgeon’s Rest Server and Rest Client to buid codeigniter restful api. however I am encountering the following error message:

=============================================
REST Test

=============================================
Request

## http://localhost/mb/api/data/50

Response

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: base64

Filename: libraries/REST_Controller.php

Line Number: 1866

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\MB\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php
Line: 1866
Function: _error_handler    


File: D:\xampp\htdocs\MB\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php
Line: 2005
Function: _check_login  


File: D:\xampp\htdocs\MB\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php
Line: 519
Function: _prepare_mb_auth  


File: D:\xampp\htdocs\MB\application\controllers\API.php
Line: 10
Function: __construct   


File: D:\xampp\htdocs\MB\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

## not authorized{"status":false,"error":"Not authorized"}

Call details

Comment: what is your authorization is it basic? If yes, have you provided Authorization header? Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTExMQ== NOTE:YWRtaW46MTExMQ== is base64 encode of admin:1111

Comment: @Calvin yes it is basic

Comment: @Calvin kindly explain to me exactly where to place authorization header

Comment: You access the link via browser?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a http header when accessing API Link
`Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTExMQ==`
`YWRtaW46MTExMQ==` is the passphrase encoded in base64
if decoded it is

```
admin:1111
```

`admin` is your username
`1111` is your password
Website to encode decode base https://www.base64encode.org/
You can use postman 
https://www.getpostman.com/ to provide Authorization header or
When accessing link on browser you can fill the alert box with username and password

You can find your username and password at `application/config/rest.php`
find a config of `$config[rest_valid_logins]=`

Comment: I have a table name users with login pass:1234, username:admin.kindly explain the logic here

Comment: Try to provide header Authorization: Basic (base64 encode of admin:1234) Details about it is on this answer.

Comment: the encryption type provided in the library is hash. and when I run it using the postman it gives Undefined index: hash. even when I change it to base64. the error only disappears when I get rid of it

Comment: do you mean $config['auth_library_class'] = '';
$config['auth_library_function'] = '';?

Comment: I have edited the question for fullstack error. kindly check

Comment: Can i see a few line around 1866 at libraries/REST_Controller.php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150889/discussion-between-calvin-and-vinn).

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to disable authentication; it's simple: goto
>   config/rest.php Change;  $config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';   to 
>   $config['rest_auth'] = '';  Else, in header of your API request you
>   have to send AUTH credential listed in:  $config['rest_valid_logins']
>   = array('admin' => '1234');
>
> NOTE:If you facing problem, you should change your .htaccess as
>   following:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine on
        SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
        #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

    </IfModule>
```

> If you still has problem, change code of libraries\REST_Controller.php
>
> Find this in your code:

```
    elseif ($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION')) 
    { 
      if (strpos(strtolower($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION')), 'basic') === 0) 
      {
          list($username, $password) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'), 6)));
      }
    }
```

> and replace with:

```
    elseif ( $this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION') || $this->input->server('REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER') || $this->input->server('REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION') )
                  {

                    $HTTP_SERVER_AUTH = ($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION')) ? $this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION') : $this->input->server('REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'); 
                   if(!$HTTP_SERVER_AUTH)
                   {
                     $HTTP_SERVER_AUTH = $this->input->server('REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'); 
                   }


                    if (strpos(strtolower($HTTP_SERVER_AUTH),'basic') === 0)
                    {
                        list($username,$password) = explode(':',base64_decode(substr($HTTP_SERVER_AUTH, 6)));
                    }

                }
```